# How to show the splashscreen for android? Cordova

Tags: javascript, css, ios-simulator, media-queries

Here's my procedure through the CLI

> cordova create project

-

> cordova platform add android

-

> i created my own res folder into the root of the project

-

> then copied all the files to the respective folder and added the configuration to the config.xml that exists in the root of project: it looks like this

This is where i picked each splashscreen size: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes

```
<gap:splash src="res/android/drawable-port-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/android/drawable-port-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi"  gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/android/drawable-port-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi"  gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/android/drawable-port-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi"  gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"/>

<gap:splash src="res/android/drawable-land-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" gap:qualifier="land-ldpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/android/drawable-land-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi"  gap:qualifier="land-mdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/android/drawable-land-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi"  gap:qualifier="land-hdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/android/drawable-land-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi"  gap:qualifier="land-xhdpi"/>
```

-

> but still, the splashscreen doesn't show

Then I went to the phonegap documentation and found something related to the splashscreen plugin. 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen#android-quirks

For me it's not clear what value should be given to foo
and not even where i should put the file. Also, the plugin doesn't specify how it works for NON 9patch images.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to provide a default one:

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" width="320" height="125" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work. But the same configuration built trough build.phonegap.com works perfectly. The most interesting part is that the CLI finds the images and copy them to the appropriate location inside /platforms/.../res but no splashscreen is shown

Comment: If this helps you: http://ionicframework.com/blog/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/